# How do I capitalize all words in a string apart from small words in the middle and in the beginning?

Tags: ruby

I have a long string, "the silver rider on his back and the palm tree". I would like to write a Ruby method that capitalizes all words except "on", "the", and "and" in the middle of the sentence, but have the "the" capitalized at the beginning?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def title(word)
  small_words = %w[on the and]
  word.split(' ').map  do |w|
    unless small_words.include?(w)
      w.capitalize
    else
      w
    end
  end.join(' ')
end
```

This code actually does most of what I need but don't know how to include or exclude for that matter the "the" at the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will capitalize all the words, except for the stop words (your small words) that aren't the first in the sentence.

```
def title(sentence)
  stop_words = %w{a an and the or for of nor} #there is no such thing as a definite list of stop words, so you may edit it according to your needs.
  sentence.split.each_with_index.map{|word, index| stop_words.include?(word) && index > 0 ? word : word.capitalize }.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Awesome Cezar! That's just what I was looking for. I just couldn't see 'each_with_index' being very useful indeed.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it solved the problem. Also, you should do the same for answers to other questions you've asked on Stack Overflow. This is useful to reward people who answer questions correctly, while at the same time allows other users to benefit from questions you've asked by easily identifying good answers.

Comment: How do I accept your answer? Where in the stackoverflow? Not using it much.

Comment: In order to accept the answer, click the white checkmark next to it. To upvote it, click the up arrow above the zero. Also refer to this page http://stackoverflow.com/about It will teach you how to use Stack Overflow in a more beneffitial way both to you and the community as a whole.

Comment: Got it:) Thanks for reminding me of others who participated as well and the old posts I haven't gotten through to vote either. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. You can also reward all the answers that have helped you, both the accepted and the non accepted, by giving then an upvote. Think of the upvote as marking a answer as useful, and the accept as marking the answer as the best one.

Answer (score 2):

It’s easiest to just forget about the special case of the first letter initially and then handle it after doing everything else:

```
def title(sentence)
  small_words = %w[on the and]

  capitalized_words = sentence.split(' ').map do |word|
    small_words.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize
  end
  capitalized_words.first.capitalize!

  capitalized_words.join(' ')
end
```

This also capitalizes *any* “small word” at the beginning, not just “the”—but I think that’s probably what you want anyway.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Andrew. Your code only works for a first letter in the sentence, everything else is lower case though. What I need is something like this; "The Silver Rider on His Back and the Palm Tree" and not "The silver rider on his back and the palm tree".

Comment: `capitalize` => Modifies str by converting the first character to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. Your function has the same effect of just calling capitalize on the input string.

Comment: I am amazed how quickly you guys jumped to help. Thank you all!

Comment: @Cezar Right you are. Forgot that `capitalize` was a core method and assumed the OP had their own implementation, hence why I previously noted my assumption about what `capitalize` did.

Answer (score 0):

A simple mod to your existing code would make it work:

```
def title( word )
  small_words = %w[on the and]
  word.split(' ').map.with_index do |w, i|
    unless (small_words.include? w) and (i > 0)
      w.capitalize
    else
      w
    end
  end.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: @NicholasAlek It's essentially the same solution that Cezar posted later. His is just written more compactly.

Answer (score -1):

```
SmallWords = %w[on the and]
def title word
  word.gsub(/[\w']+/){
    SmallWords.include?($&) && $~.begin(0).zero?.! ? $& : $&.capitalize
  }
end
```

Comment: Why `(...).!` instead of `!(...)`?

Comment: Why `!(...)` instead of `(...).!`?

Comment: By "idiomatic", you mean more people use it? I don't care about that. I care about consistency. All other methods are chained: We start with the receiver `$~`, then `begin` applies, then `zero?` applies, then `!` applies. I don't see any reason to suddenly switch to use the prefix notation for the method `!`.

Comment: First, the `!` in `!(...)` is not a method, it’s an operator, so the consistency argument goes right out the window there. And would you really do `2.+(2).-` instead of `-(2 + 2)`?

Comment: If the prefixed `!` is not a method, then there is even more argument for consistency. Why suddenly use an operator just for `!`  when other methods are chained and can be further continued with the method `!`? Regarding `2.+(2).-`, I don't think that is valid Ruby code, so I don't do that.

Comment: Whoops, meant `2.+(2).-@`, which is valid and equivalent to `-(2 + 2)`. Too much discussion, though.

Comment: In case of `-(2 + 2)`, it is not clearly the case that the first `2` is the receiver and the second `2` is a modifier to it. It makes more sense to look it symmetrically. So `-(2 + 2)` might be better, but it depends on the context. Also, `-` (in the sense of `-@`) is better conceived as an element to write negative numbers rather than shorthand for doing "multiply by -1".

Comment: If you care about consistency, then you should consider the consistency of idiomatic use. Don't use camel-case constants like `SmallWords`. Use "SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE" per https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide and https://github.com/styleguide/ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan There's also consistency there. Modules are written in camel case, and I don't see any reason to use snake case just for other types of constants (Ruby core does, but it is inconsistent).